# NSFetchedResultsController attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update with userInfo (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i use `NSFetchedResultsController` with `UITableViewController`.
i successfully add new ocject to core data in separated view,

```
ParseStarterProjectAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newWorkout;
newWorkout = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Workouts" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newWorkout setValue:_workOutType forKey:@"type"];
[newWorkout setValue:_boostDate forKey:@"date"];
[newWorkout setValue:_workoutText forKey:@"text"];
[newWorkout setValue:_trainerLabelOutlet.text forKey:@"text"];
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}else{
    NSLog(@"saved to core data");
}
```

but i get this error :
`An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update with userInfo (null)`

the code in the `UITableViewController`:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Workouts" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id  sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WorkoutObject *workout = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = workout.text;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd   HH:mm"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:workout.date];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = dateString;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Set up the cell...
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;    
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?
i try to figure it out myself for the past 2 days but i incapable to.
thanks

Comment: Does `sectionInfo` in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns actual number of objects during inserting?

Comment: Can you make sure that `_fetchedResultsController` is not `nil` in `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: @moby good point. I think replacing `_fetchedResultsController` with `self.fetchedResultsController` might fix the issue (as it will trigger the lazy init of the controller)

Comment: the first view is the table that in the viewDidLoad Perform a fetch from Core Data and if it's nil it's set it  (- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController). the second view do the add function to the core data.i check the results from the core data and it's added successfully

Comment: update: i changed it to self.fetchResultController but it's still the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue - in my case it turned out to be because the table view data source and delegates hadn't been assigned to the view controller on the storyboard in the outlets section of the attributes inspector.  Hence numberOfRowsForSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView were not being called.

Comment: Even though I was setting dataSource and delegate in init I was getting these errors. Wired them up in Storyboard and it's running perfectly now.